# How to programatically add elements in wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a visual mock-up of a window on a wpf application I'm trying to program, but I'm struggling to come up with a solution to an issue. My goal is to list a bunch of zip files, extract them, and show their status (the goal of this window is beyond simple extraction, as I have to extract the file, clean up some files, and I need to show that status to the user). I have threads for the progress bar filling and the extraction itself, and I have the algorithm to populate the list with the items (they're stored in a string[] and I foreach that list and filter out the non-zip files and add the valid files to the window).
The issue is that for the progressbar to be there, I am unable (afaik) to use a listbox, which is what I was previously using. I need help figuring how to add the progress bar, link it to the file and update it. In theory, on the programming side, it would be as simple as naming every progress bar something unique, storing the name on the array and feeding that to the update function. However, I have no clue what elements I should use in the middle section to store the file names, and how to add the progress bars to the window in a grid-like fashion in front of the file name.

[This is the visual mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIV7x.png)

Answer (score 0):

ListBox is the correct control to use, you just need to template the ItemsPanel and ItemTemplate to look however you want. If you only want to render the items without the ListBox-specific functionality (selection etc) then use an ItemsControl instead.